# How to use children with React Stateless Functional Component in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Using TypeScript with React we no longer have to extend `React.Props` in order for the compiler to know that all react component props can have children:

```
interface MyProps { }

class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyProps, {}> {
  public render(): JSX.Element {
    return <div>{this.props.children}</div>;
  }
}
```

However, it doesn't seem to be the case for stateless functional components:

```
const MyStatelessComponent = (props: MyProps) => {
  return (
    <div>{props.children}</div>
  );
};
```

Emits the compile error:

> Error:(102, 17) TS2339: Property 'children' does not exist on type
> 'MyProps'.

I guess this is because there's really no way for the compiler to know that a vanilla function is going to be given `children` in the props argument.

So the question is how should we use children in a stateless functional component in TypeScript?

I could go back to the old way of `MyProps extends React.Props`, but the `Props` interface is [marked as deprecated](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L1313), and stateless components don't have or support a `Props.ref` as I understand it.

So I could define the `children` prop manually:

```
interface MyProps {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}
```

First: is `ReactNode` the correct type?

Second: I have to write children as optional (`?`) or else consumers will think that `children` is supposed to be an *attribute* of the component (`<MyStatelessComponent children={} />`), and raise an error if not provided with a value.

It seems like I'm missing something. Can anyone provide some clarity on whether my last example is the way to use stateless functional components with children in React?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

**React 16.8 Update:**
Since React 16.8, the names `React.SFC` and `React.StatelessComponent` are deprecated. Actually, they have become aliases for `React.FunctionComponent` type or `React.FC` for short.

You would use them the same way though:

```
const MyStatelessComponent : React.FunctionComponent<MyProps> = props =>
    <div>
        <p>{props.propInMyProps}</p>
        <p>{props.children}</p>
    </div>
```

**Before React 16.8 (Older):**

For now, you can use the `React.StatelessComponent<>` type, as:

```
const MyStatelessComponent : React.StatelessComponent<{}> = props =>
    <div>{props.children}</div>
```

What I have added there is setting the return type of the component to `React.StatelessComponent` type.

For a component with your own custom props (like `MyProps` interface):

```
const MyStatelessComponent : React.StatelessComponent<MyProps> = props =>
    <div>
        <p>{props.propInMyProps}</p>
        <p>{props.children}</p>
    </div>
```

Now, `props` has got the `children` property as well as those from `MyProps` interface.

I checked this in typescript version 2.0.7

Additionally, you can use `React.SFC` instead of `React.StatelessComponent` for brevity.

Comment: Thanks! It seems I'm on an old version of the typings that doesn't support this... I guess it's time to bite the bullet and use TS 2.0 with `@types`

Comment: `React.StatelessComponent` / `React.SFC` are deprecated. It is recommended to refer to `React.FunctionComponent` instead.

Comment: Note that this method does not work if you have a generic component

Answer (score 181):

You can use `React.PropsWithChildren<P>` type for your props:

```
interface MyProps { }

function MyComponent(props: React.PropsWithChildren<MyProps>) {
  return <div>{props.children}</div>;
}
```

Comment: I think this answer may be considered the correct answer for now. Due to the discouragement of `React.FunctionComponent` (or the shorthand React.FC) in [React Typescript Cheatsheet](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/function_components).

Comment: The answer is nearly working, but for me with an arrow function definition, `const MyComponent: React.FunctionComponent<React.PropsWithChildren<MyProps>> = (props) => ( ... )` is required (typing the props variable directly, as per the answer, does not seem to get rid of all errors).

Comment: @MikeBeaton For arrow functions your props are implicitly typed to have all the same props as `PropsWithChildren`, so there is no need to add that. That is just overhead. Just write FunctionComponent<MyProps>

Comment: @oligofren - With that change, it actually compiles and runs, but in my VS Code window I am getting an error highlighted with `Property 'children' does not exist on type '{}'.`. (Actually, no, the tests compile and run, but in the full build that change also causes: `TS2559: Type '{ children: Element; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.`)

Answer (score 17):

Simpler answer: Use `ReactNode`:

```js
interface MyProps {
  children?: React.ReactNode
}
```

If `children` is optional or not (i.e. having `?` or not) depends on your component. The `?` is the most concise way to express that, so nothing wrong with that.

On history: This was not necessarily the correct answer back when originally asked: The type `ReactNode` was added in (almost) its current form in March 2017 [by this pull request](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/9101/files?file-filters%5B%5D=.js&w=1) only, but almost everyone reading this today *should* be on a modern enough version of React.

Lastly, about passing `children` as "attribute" (which, in React lingo, would be passing it as "prop", not attribute): It is possible, but in most cases reads better when passing JSX children:

```
<MyComponent>
  <p>This is part of the children.</p>
</MyComponent>
```

reads more easily than

```
<MyComponent children={<p>This is part of the children.</p>} />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add children to the component and if it is connected to a container that is all you need.

```
const MyComponent = ({ 
   children  
}) => {
  return <div>{children}</div>

}
```

Comment: And it was a TypeScript question.

Answer (score 0):

Personally it's pretty easy in later versions of react when using typescript such as Next-JS 14

```
export default function TwButton({children, type, role } : {children?: 
 ReactNode,
        type?:"submit" | "reset" | "button",
        role?: "OK" | "CANCEL" | "RESET"
         }){
....
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use

```
interface YourProps { }
const yourComponent: React.SFC<YourProps> = props => {}
```

Comment: `React.SFC` is deprecated