# Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `loading`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I've created a custom button component based on [Material-UI's Button component](https://material-ui.com/api/button/), so I can overlay a loading circle whenever an action is pending. However, React complains with the following:

**Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `loading`.
If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: loading="false" or loading={value.toString()}.**

Here's what my component looks like. Thanks in advance!

```js
import * as React from 'react'
import { ButtonProps } from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import { Button, CircularProgress } from '@material-ui/core'

interface IProps extends ButtonProps {
    loading: boolean
}

export const LoadingButton = (props: IProps) => {
    const { disabled, loading } = props
    return (
        <div className='button-container'>
            <Button {...props} disabled={disabled == true || loading == true}/>
            {loading == true && (
                <CircularProgress size={24} className='button-progress' />
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: This may help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44375759/how-should-i-declare-a-stateless-functional-component-with-typescript-in-react

Comment: This doesn't address my issue, which is a JavaScript error (not a TypScript error)

Comment: How are you calling the component? `<LoadingButton disabled={false} loading="false">My Button</LoadingButton>`

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You shouldn't pass your *custom* props down to the Button.

Replace

```
const { disabled, loading } = props
```

with

```
const { disabled, loading, ...rest } = props
```

and then

```
<Button {...rest} disabled={disabled || loading}/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are passing all your props to the `Button` component. Remove `{...props}` from `<Button />` and declare the attributes separately.

Looking at the documentation, you can see that `loading` it is not an attribute on the `Button` component, but the spread operator `...` still add it.

```
<div className="button-container">
      <Button disabled={disabled === true || loading === true} />
      {loading === true && <CircularProgress size={24} className="button-progress" />}
    </div>
  )
```

Also, as a side note, I recommend that you use the `===` identity operator instead of the `==` equality operator. See this post [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: This wouldn't work in the case where I pass, for example, `onClick: () => void` to the `<LoadingButton>`. The underlying `<Button>` wouldn't receive it.