# React + Typescript: Type of React component with no state/no props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've seen multiple examples of React components using Typescript:

`class Foo extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {}`

It seems there is no a clear convention when we don't use either the Props or the State.

People set these types as `any`, `null`,`undefined`,`{}`, <s>`void`</s>, etc.This is what I've seen so far:

1. `class Foo extends React.Component<null, null> {}`
2. `class Foo extends React.Component<any, any> {}`
3. `class Foo extends React.Component<{}, {}> {}`
4. `class Foo extends React.Component<undefined, undefined> {}`
5. <s>`class Foo extends React.Component<void, void> {}`</s>
6. `class Foo extends React.Component<object, object> {}`

What's the best way of doing it?

**Update:**

- **Props:**

  - `void` **cannot** be used  (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15409 and https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15419 ) as the props object is initialised to `{}`

**SOLUTION**

Simply do - `class Foo extends React.Component {}` as prop and state are initialised to `{}`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/15b7bac31972fbc081028937dfb1487507ca5fc9/types/react/index.d.ts#L199-L200

```
interface Component<P = {}, S = {}> extends ComponentLifecycle<P, S> { }
```

Props and state are initialised to `{}`, so for a component with no state nor prop we can simply do:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {}
```

Answer (score 24):

As answered [for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40748397/how-to-use-children-with-react-stateless-functional-component-in-typescript?answertab=active#tab-top), you can use the `React.FC<{}>` class

```
const MyStatelessComponent : React.FC<{}> = props =>
    <div>{props.children}</div>
```

Or if your markup gets bigger:

```
const MyStatelessComponent : React.FC<{}> = props => {

    {/*  Some code here */}
    return <div>{props.children}</div>

}
```

Comment: `React.SFC<{}>` can as well be refactored to `React.FC<{}>`  or `React.FunctionComponent<{}>` since hooks introduced State in functional components.

Comment: If you are using TS and it is complaining about `FC<{}>`, you can reduce it to just `FC` without the angle and curly brackets.  Working example: `const MyComponent: FC = () => { /* code and tsx here */ }`

Answer (score 14):

According to [this guideline](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html) and my exp, I would say :

1. `class Foo extends React.Component<null, null> {}` when you know you will not recieve props nor state
2. `class Foo extends React.Component<any, any> {}` when you know you will recieve props and state but you really don't care what they look like
3. `class Foo extends React.Component<{}, {}> {}` never saw, seems strange
4. `class Foo extends React.Component<undefined, undefined> {}` same as `null`, it's up to you. I see more often `null` than `undefined`
5. `class Foo extends React.Component<void, void> {}` bad idea, since seems to be reserved for functions return (when you do not expect one)

Other opinions are welcomed

Comment: I´ve seen some people having problems with `void` as a change in a recent version initialises the props to {}

Comment: If I used `null` then I get this error: *Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'null'*

Comment: @Al.G. same here. Obviously missing out the angle brackets is the best if you have neither props nor state,but if you have one or the other, I think `{}`  is the best option

Answer (score 8):

You can use `VoidFunctionComponent` for stateless ans propless components (without state ana props):

```
const MyComponent: React.VoidFunctionComponent = () => {
  ...
}
```

Comment: `React.VoidFunctionComponent` has been deprecated in React 18

Answer (score 2):

I always create a props Interface for each component, even if it's blank. It keeps things consistant and allows me to easily add props later if needed.

```
Interface FooProps { }

class foo extends React.Component<FooProps, any> {
}
```

Comment: Do you do the same thing for the state?

Comment: You can. I've typically just been leaving that as "any". I'm using react-redux to manage state and the only time I've needed a local state was for input fields.

Answer (score 1):

Stateful(class based components) & Stateless components there's a lot of conceptions on the internet about when use one or another, I've grasped these concepts using this list (before have practical experience):

**Stateless**

1. Are concerned with how things look.
2. May contain both presentational and container components** inside,
   and usually have some DOM markup and styles of their own.
3. Often allow containment via this.props.children.
4. Have no dependencies on the rest of the app, such as Flux actions or
   stores.
5. Don’t specify how the data is loaded or mutated.
6. Receive data and callbacks exclusively via props.
7. Are written as functional components

**Examples:  Menu, UserInfo, List, SideBar.**

**Stateful**

1. Are concerned with how things work.
2. May contain both presentational and container components** inside
   but usually don’t have any DOM markup of their own except for some
   wrapping divs, and never have any styles.
3. Provide the data and behavior to presentational or other container
   components.
4. Call Redux actions and provide these as callbacks to the
   presentational components.

**Examples: UserPage, FollowersSidebar, ArticlesContainer.**

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I meant what of the examples I put is the right way of doing it. I´ve edited the question to make it clearer