# React.JS prop is not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Here is the piece of my index.ts code (where I call the component to display)

```
        <GlobalContext.Provider value={this.globalContext as IGlobalContext}>
            <Container maxWidth="lg">
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="" component={HelloWorld} elements={this.getResults()}/>
                </Switch>
            </Container>
        </GlobalContext.Provider>
```

Here is the piece of the helloWorld.ts file (the beggining)

```
import React from 'react';

export default class HelloWorld extends React.Component {

    public render(): JSX.Element {
        let elements = this.props.elements; // I Want to get the elements props passed throuth my router component
        ....
```

Why can't I get the this.props.elements in the helloWorld.ts file ? How can I do it ?

I Have the error : **Property 'elements' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.  TS2339**

Comment: Without the error message you're getting, it's hard to determine your problem. You also want to create a minimal working example to show what you're doing.

Comment: Yes, I edited my post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property 'XYZ' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<{}>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249390/property-xyz-does-not-exist-on-type-readonly-children-reactnode-rea)

Comment: Does `elements` exist on the Route element?

Comment: @DispénNém did the answer solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Use constructor and also lose the '**this**' in render method.

```
   constructor(props)
{
    super(props);
}

public render(): JSX.Element {
 let elements = props.elements;
            ....
```

Just use `props.elements` instead of `this.props.elements`