# What is the type of the 'children' prop?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, typescript2.0

I have a very simple functional component as follows:

```
import * as React from 'react';

export interface AuxProps  { 
    children: React.ReactNode
 }


const aux = (props: AuxProps) => props.children;

export default aux;
```

And another component:

```
import * as React from "react";

export interface LayoutProps  { 
   children: React.ReactNode
}

const layout = (props: LayoutProps) => (
    <Aux>
        <div>Toolbar, SideDrawer, Backdrop</div>
        <main>
            {props.children}
        </main>
    <Aux/>
);

export default layout;
```

I keep on getting the following error:

> [ts]
>   JSX element type 'ReactNode' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
>     Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ElementClass'. [2605]

How do I type this correctly?

Comment: To avoid reinventing wheel, you can alternatively use React.FC to define your Functional Component. i e., `const layout React.FC = (props) => {/*component body*/}`

Comment: you can use const XyzComponent = `({ title, children }: React.PropsWithChildren<XyzComponentPropsType>` => {}`

Answer (score 949):

Just `children: React.ReactNode`.

Comment: This is the correct answer here ! `JSX.Element` is not good enough since a valid React children could be a string, a boolean, null... `ReactChild` is incomplete too for the same reasons

Comment: @PierreFerry The issue is, almost *anything* can be assigned to `ReactNode`. It doesn't help in terms of type safety, similar to typing `children` as `any` - see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60721650/5669456) for an explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your response @ford04. In my use case i want children to be loosely type. My component accept any kind of valid React children. So i believe this is still the answer i was looking for :)

Comment: or `PropsWithChildren`

Comment: Confused...isn't that what OP already has?

Comment: @JanacMeena it's funny but people were finding this question when didn't know what type they should add to the children's element. It's simply just one of the first topics on Google. So if you don't know what TS type add to the element you probably will google something like "typescript react children", find this topic and the first answer, even if the question is quite about something different :)

Comment: With this answer, I get "object is possibly undefined" pointing at the `this` in `this.props.children`

Comment: Adding that `JSX.Element` is also not good because you can't pass multiple elements to it (without using a fragment).

Comment: React.ReactNode does not allow multiple elements as children though.

Comment: I would add `| React.ReactNode[]` to also allow multiple children

Comment: The `React.ReactNode` type does allow multiple children. It is a union type which includes `ReactFragment`, another union type which includes `Iterable<ReactNode>` (in older versions of React it was `Array<ReactNode>`)

Code here: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/shared/ReactTypes.js

Therefore, an array of `ReactNode`s is already a valid `ReactNode`. You shouldn't need to use `| React.ReactNode[]`

Comment: this answer does not help with a proper explanation for @Ridd. 

"When you pass PropsWithChildren to your component prop FooProps, you get the children prop internally typed.

In most cases, this is the recommended way to go about typing the children prop because it requires less boilerplate and the children prop is implicitly typed." - this article helped me understand the child prop type fully: https://blog.logrocket.com/using-react-children-prop-with-typescript/#using-functioncomponent-fc-type

Answer (score 129):

In order to use `<Aux>` in your JSX, it needs to be a function that returns `ReactElement<any> | null`. That's the definition of a *function component*.

However, it's currently defined as a function that returns `React.ReactNode`, which is a much wider type. As React typings say:

```
type ReactNode = ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined;
```

Make sure the unwanted types are neutralized by wrapping the returned value into React Fragment (`<></>`):

```
const aux: React.FC<AuxProps> = props =>
  <>{props.children}</>;
```

Comment: I don't understand why it's needed to wrap `children` in a React Fragment. Care to explain? In React it's perfectly valid to just `return children;`.

Comment: Not if `children` are an array. If that's the case you need to either wrap them in a single node or use React Fragments.

Comment: Yeah, in my code I have:
`return React.Children.count(children) > 1 ? <>{children}</> : children`, but typescript complains about that. I replaced it with just `<>{children}</>`.

Comment: It complains because `children` is a list of elements that happens to contain only 1 item. I think it would work if you did `return React.Children.count(children) > 1 ? <>{children}</> : children[0]` @sanfilippopablo

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working in newer versions of React.  I console logged and can confirm that I have a children prop, but even with ```<React.Fragment>``` surrounding ```{props.children}``` I am not returning anything.

Comment: How about when `children` is a function?

Comment: Wrappping into the Fragment <></> - here is the point! Thanks)

Comment: With this, I got an error of '<component>' components don't accept text as child elements. Text in JSX has the type 'string', but the expected type of 'children' is 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | null'.ts(2747)` when the children of the component was a string. How would I fix that?

Answer (score 101):

You can also use `React.PropsWithChildren<P>`.

```
type ComponentWithChildProps = React.PropsWithChildren<{example?: string}>;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I've been doing and I think it's the cleaner way to use the right typing.

Comment: I like this solution because it is extensible. `type AuthProviderProps = React.PropsWithChildren<{}>` allows me to encapsulate React types, and extend with my own when needed.

Comment: cleanest way, the one i was looking for

Comment: This feels the cleanest because it's using React's own published types so if the definition of what constitutes a react child changes in future versions of React, it is reasonable to assume that this type will also be updated. Solutions based on `ReactChild | ReactChildren`, would probably need to be updated in that case.

Answer (score 91):

You can use `ReactChildren` and `ReactChild`:

```
import React, { ReactChildren, ReactChild } from 'react';
 
interface AuxProps {
  children: ReactChild | ReactChildren;
}

const Aux = ({ children }: AuxProps) => (<div>{children}</div>);

export default Aux;
```

If you need to pass flat arrays of elements:

```
interface AuxProps {
  children: ReactChild | ReactChild[] | ReactChildren | ReactChildren[];
}
```

Comment: For anyone who ended up here, this is wrong.  

`ReactChildren` does not equal to `ReactChild[]` since it is type for utility function.
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren. 


if you use `ReactChild | ReactChildren` , you won't be able to pass children as an array.

Comment: @kay Thanks for that. I added the flat arrays definition to the answer. It should cover your case too. Let me know.

Comment: thank you!  However, I don't think `ReactChildren` is the right type here.   

I think `children: ReactChild | ReactChild[]` is enough or just `ReactNode`

Comment: I disagree. Its better to create a type/interface as `ReactNode` compared to `ReactChild` and `ReactChildren` since it accepts more than just ReactChild/ReactChildren. Or even better, use `PropsWithChildren` as others have mentioned.

Comment: @deprecated — - This type is not relevant when using React. Inline the type instead to make the intent clear.

Comment: `ReactChild` was deprecated starting in React 18, but if you want to require the children to be passed, you can do: `NonNullable<React.ReactNode>`. (NonNullable is a built-in Typescript utility type)

Answer (score 84):

This is what worked for me:

```
interface Props {
  children: JSX.Element[] | JSX.Element
}
```

**Edit** I would recommend using `children: React.ReactNode` instead now.

Comment: That's not broad enough of a definition. The child could be a string.

Comment: At least this example worked for me since my component was supposed to expect 1 or more JSX.Elements. Thanks!

Comment: This will not work with JavaScript expressions as the children `<MyComponent>{ condition ? <span>test</span> : null}</MyComponent>`. Using `children: ReactNode` will work.

Comment: or use `PropsWithChildren` as others have mentioned. I personally prefer it to `children: React.ReactNode`

Answer (score 25):

A `React Node` is one of the following types:

- `Boolean` (which is ignored)
- `null` or `undefined` (which is ignored)
- `Number`
- `String`
- A `React element` (result of `JSX`)
- An array of any of the above, possibly a nested one

Answer (score 19):

```
import { ReactNode, FC } from 'react'

type Props = { children: ReactNode }

const App: FC<Props> = ({children}) => (<div>{children}</div>)
```

Comment: FC already has children, so no need to redeclare it

Answer (score 16):

I'm using the following

```
type Props = { children: React.ReactNode };

const MyComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      { children }
    </div>
  );

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: the general consensus today is that React.FunctionComponent (or the shorthand React.FC) is [discouraged](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177). In your case, I would remove `React.FC` usage and just do `const MyComponent = ({children}: PropsWithChildren<{}>)`

Comment: propsWithChildren<{}> however also introduces some codesmells with {} being any

Comment: If you are using `React.FC`, there is no need to include `children` type, as it is already defined on the base FC typings.

Answer (score 15):

you can declare your component like this:

```
const MyComponent: React.FunctionComponent = (props) => {
    return props.children;
}
```

Comment: the general consensus today is that React.FunctionComponent (or the shorthand React.FC) is [discouraged](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177). In your case, I would remove `React.FC` usage and just do `const MyComponent = ({children}: PropsWithChildren<{}>)`

Answer (score 15):

The function component return type is limited to `JSXElement | null` in TypeScript. This is a current type limitation, pure React [allows more](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render) return types.

[Minimal demonstration snippet](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wFgAoCpAD0ljmADsYkpN0k4BBAV2oAUcYAM5wA3hThS4aABbAANgBMijAFyJiMAHTJ0MAHIQlSCgF8KFNBEbD4vanAC8cABRghwjQ8EQRASmcAPjgPP2FtOUUVJEYAbktya1t4ABkUAE8IHngXV0CnENdJaQB6UrgeWQBaCFkSqQAeByCG6SalYAA3IIAVCAgFACMUKAAaOABlYBMAESgUAHdWCYAhdABrFT84RtLOnra9lop-IA)

You can either use a type assertion or Fragments as workaround:

```
const Aux = (props: AuxProps) => <>props.children</>; 
const Aux2 = (props: AuxProps) => props.children as ReactElement;
```

---

#### `ReactNode`

`children: React.ReactNode` might be suboptimal, if the goal is to have strong types for `Aux`.

Almost anything can be assigned to current `ReactNode` type, which is equivalent to `{} | undefined | null`. A safer type for your case could be:

```
interface AuxProps {
  children: ReactElement | ReactElement[]
}
```

Example:

Given `Aux` needs React elements as `children`, we accidently added a `string` to it. Then [above solution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=12&ssc=9&pln=12&pc=12#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDez0wCiANkiEgHYwC+cAZlBCHAERSoYsCwAUL0gA9IsOMCpIoddEjgBBAK4CACozABnXLzja4aABbBiAE3YUAXIg5FS5KnAA+lgiTKUYAbQC6var15oICjV4BQE4AF44AAowVTULUJUIdQBKCIA+OAAedNjktQA6fUMTSiyAenSAbj8eAKD4ABkUAE8IeXhIqLTwzKitHSzQ9IGdQaNgADd0gBUICGIAIxQobABlYCMkABEoFAB3CWwAIXQAaxNkionp0bH6ebuK4d4UqqA) would error in contrast to [`ReactNode`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=9&ssc=7&pln=9&pc=8#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wFgAoCpAD0ljmADsYkpN0k4BBAV2oAUcYAM5wA3hThS4aABbAANgBMijAFyJiMAHTJ0MAHIQlSCgF8KFNBEbD4vanAC8cABRghwjQ8EQRASmcAPjgAHiCPP2FtOUUVJEZQgHoggG5LcmtbeAAZFABPCB54F1dApxDXSWlQhyDq6RqlYAA3IIAVCAgFACMUKAAaOABlYBMAESgUAHdWIYAhdABrFT9k5raGxrhMLq3kuop-VKA) - take a look at the linked playgrounds.

Typed `children` are also useful for non-JSX props, like a [Render Prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html#using-props-other-than-render) callback.

Answer (score 11):

The *general* way to find any type is by example. The beauty of typescript is that you have access to **all** types, so long as you have the correct `@types/` files.

To answer this myself I just thought of a component react uses that has the `children` prop. The first thing that came to mind? How about a `<div />`?

All you need to do is open [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and create a new `.tsx` file in a react project with `@types/react`.

```
import React from 'react';

export default () => (
  <div children={'test'} />
);
```

Hovering over the `children` prop shows you the type. And what do you know -- Its type is **`ReactNode`** (no need for `ReactNode[]`).

[image]

Then if you click into the type definition it brings you straight to the definition of `children` coming from `DOMAttributes` interface.

```
// node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts
interface DOMAttributes<T> {
  children?: ReactNode;
  ...
}
```

> Note: This process should be used to find any unknown type! All of them are there just waiting for you to find them :)

Comment: Control + click (on windows) takes you to said type-definition. May be common knowledge but I had to look up. Thanks for teaching us to fish instead of just giving fish btw.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use `JSX.ElementChildrenAttribute`

```
export default function Layout({children}: JSX.ElementChildrenAttribute) {
    return <div>
        {children}
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 9):

From the TypeScript site: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6471

> The recommended practice is to write the props type as {children?:
>   any}

That worked for me. The child node can be many different things, so explicit typing can miss cases.

There's a longer discussion on the followup issue here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13618, but the any approach still works.

Answer (score 7):

These answers appear to be outdated - React now has a built in type `PropsWithChildren<{}>`. It is defined similarly to some of the correct answers on this page:

`type PropsWithChildren<P> = P & { children?: ReactNode };`

Comment: What is `P` in the case of that type?

Comment: `P` is the type of your component's props

Comment: Yes! this worked nicely. `interface LayoutProps {}

const Layout = ({children}: PropsWithChildren<LayoutProps>) => {...}`

Answer (score 7):

For me "JSX.Element" works,

```
interface childrenProps {
    children: JSX.Element;
}

const index = ({ children }: childrenProps) => {
    return (
        <>
            <NavBar />
            {children}
        </>
    );
};

export default index;
```

Comment: JSX.Element is one type that a child can be, but it could also be a String or a number, etc... `ReactNode` covers all cases, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75518267/1014841

Answer (score 6):

This has always worked for me:

```
type Props = {
  children: JSX.Element;
};
```

Comment: I would recommend just using `React.PropsWithChildren<{}>` or at least `React.ReactNode` instead of `JSX.Element` since it accpets more than just `Element` type

Comment: This work for me too. I think typescript typings is becoming messy now.

Answer (score 4):

As a type that contains children, I'm using:

```
type ChildrenContainer = Pick<JSX.IntrinsicElements["div"], "children">
```

This children container type is generic enough to support all the different cases and also aligned with the ReactJS API.

So, for your example it would be something like:

```
const layout = ({ children }: ChildrenContainer) => (
    <Aux>
        <div>Toolbar, SideDrawer, Backdrop</div>
        <main>
            {children}
        </main>
    <Aux/>
)
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to define `children` prop is to use `ReactNode` type.

It consists of:

```
type ReactNode = ReactElement | string | number | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined;
```

But if you use `FC` or `FunctionComponent` and `React < 18` like this:

```
import React, { FC } from 'react'

export const ParentComponent: FC = ({ children }) => (
  <ChildComponent>
    {children}
  </ChildComponent>
)
```

You don't have to set `children` prop. Because `FC`/`FunctionComponent` defined it for you with `PropsWithChildren`:

```
type PropsWithChildren<P> = P & { children?: ReactNode | undefined };
```

Comment: thanks, but I am using the FC type, and typescript isn't giving me the children props, I have to define it myself inside an interface when I provide it with parameter types as `FC<MyPropsInterface>`

Answer (score 3):

You can also extends  React.PropsWithChildren to your interface which contains children property.

```
interface Props extends React.PropsWithChildren{
    listItems: Items[],
    clickItem?: () => void,
    
}
```

Or you can directly define the children

```
interface Props{
    listItems: Items[],
    clickItem?: () => void,
    children: React.ReactNode  
}

const List:FC<Props> = ({listItems,clickItem,children}) =>  {

  return (
    <>
    {children}
    </>
    
  )
}
```

Or you can do like this. This is a another way to defining prop type

```
const List = ({ children }: {children: React.ReactNode}) =>  {
```

Answer (score 2):

1. you should know that any react component **should** return `null` or `React.Element`, but the type of `props.children` is `React.ReactNode`, so you need to use the `props.children` inside an `Element` to make the babel configure the constructor of the `Element`.
2. the second rule of any react component is that the first letter of the naming **should** be a capital letter to let the react recognize that the component isn't a html tag.

so the code should be like this.

```js
const Aux = (props: AuxProps) => <>props.children</>;
```

---

another hint if you still using typescript, the functional component should be type of `React.FC` like this

```js
type Props = {
   title: string;
}

const Aux:React.FC<Props> = (props) =>
(
    <div>
        <h3>{props.title}</h3>
        { props.children }
        {/* children is exist by default in type React.FC */}
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 2):

For me @Sibren's answer was not clear enough but I found [this SO anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56026992/828184) and made it all inline (that's maybe not the shortest way but the one I find the easiest to grasp).

```
function MyComponentWithChildren({
    customProp,
    children, /*notice the children are implicit*/
}: React.PropsWithChildren<{ customProp: any }>) {
    return <div>{children}</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple component that outputs just `children` prop without `type` or `interface` with `FC` (functional component). You have to wrap with empty jsx tags `<>`, as children can be `undefined` or `null`:

```
import { FC } from "react";

export const Layout: FC = (props) => {
  return <>{props.children}</>;
};
```

-- or --

```
import { FC } from "react";

export const Layout: FC = ({ children }) => <>{children}</>;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did this:

```
import React, { ReactNode } from "react";

type Props = {
  children: ReactNode;
};

export default function Outline({ children }: Props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Top</h3>
      {children}
      <h3>Botton</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is problem in return of Aux component because children can be string, null, array or element but layout component must need react element, so you have to cover up your `props.children` with div or React.Fragment. Then after every time layout component will get react element from aux component something like below.

```
import * as React from 'react';

export interface AuxProps  { 
    children: React.ReactNode
 }


const aux = (props: AuxProps) => <React.Fragment>{props.children}</React.Fragment>;

export default aux;
```

Answer (score 0):

this solution works perfectly fine for me

```
interface Props {
    children: Array<ReactElement<ChildProps, JSXElementConstructor<ChildType>>>;
}
```

**update**: a comprehensive example so that it is easier to understand.

```
interface ChildProps {}

class ChildComponent extends React.Component<ChildProps> {}

interface ParentProps {
    children: Array<ReactElement<ChildProps, JSXElementConstructor<ChildComponent>>>;
}

class ParentComponent extends React.Component<ParentProps> {}
```

Comment: If your "children" should be safely typed, within your parent component, this the one and only solution. Thank you very much, Sir!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `children: PropsWithChildren<{}>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *require* that children are passed in to your component without allowing null/undefined children, you can use:

```js
  children: NonNullable<React.ReactNode>
```

([NonNullable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) is a built-in TypeScript utility type that excludes null and undefined from any type.)

Note: there is one loophole here - it allows an empty array of `ReactNode` objects to be passed in. If you want to prevent that case then you'd need to create your own custom more explicit type.

Otherwise (if you want to allow children to be empty or you don't care), use `React.PropsWithChildren` or `children: React.ReactNode` as recommended in other answers here, and that will cover all possible types of children (or no children).

Answer (score -1):

```
children: ReactElement
```

worked for me.