# When creating an interface, what does it mean to use children: React.ReactNode?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've used this a couple of times when creating a component in React using Typescript, but still not 100% certain what it means to specify 'children: React.ReactNode'. 
Looking for an explanation please.

Comment: Maybe related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53688899/typescript-and-react-children-type)? There is also a good answer.

Comment: You are welcome. I'm not familiar with TypeScript but there is a good explanation of why you use `React.ReactNode` as type since it is defined as it may include `React.Child`.

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting the component to return React children components. 
(Seems pretty obvious now I know the answer)