# How to pass children type to props of HOC react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to TypeScript and I am struggling to write HOC with typecheck.
Here's my HOC:

```
import React from 'react';
import Firebase from './Firebase';

export type FirebaseType = Firebase;

interface OwnProps {
  firebase: typeof Firebase;
}

const FirebaseContext = React.createContext(new Firebase());

export const withFirebase: React.FC = <T extends OwnProps>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<T>,
): React.ComponentType<T> => (props) => (
  <FirebaseContext.Consumer>
    {(firebase: FirebaseType) => <Component {...props} firebase={firebase} />}
  </FirebaseContext.Consumer>
);

export default FirebaseContext;
```

It throws an error:

> Type '(Component: React.ComponentType) =>
>   React.ComponentType' is not assignable to type 'FC<{}>'.   Types of
>   parameters 'Component' and 'props' are incompatible.
>       Type '{ children?: ReactNode; }' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType'.
>         Type '{ children?: ReactNode; }' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent'.
>           Type '{ children?: ReactNode; }' provides no match for the signature '(props: PropsWithChildren, context?: any):
>   ReactElement ReactElement Component)> | null) | (new
>   (props: any) => Component<...>)> | null'.ts(2322)

I have ***absolutely no idea*** how to move on with this code or how to make it work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Dear @VasylButov, you can react [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53688899). maybe it helps you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what that error means:

In your type definition, you're expecting `withFirebase` to have the same type signature as a function component (`React.FC`), which takes in `props` and returns a React element (or null).

However, that's not what you want from a HOC, you want it to take in a Component (`React.ComponentType`) and return a Component (`React.ComponentType`).

This should work:

```
type HOC = (Component: React.ComponentType) => React.ComponentType;
// Or, if you want to be more specific:
// type HOC = <T extends OwnProps>(Component: React.ComponentType<T>) => React.ComponentType<T>

export const withFirebase: HOC = <T extends OwnProps>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<T>,
): React.ComponentType<T> => (props) => (
  <FirebaseContext.Consumer>
    {(firebase: FirebaseType) => <Component {...props} firebase={firebase} />}
  </FirebaseContext.Consumer>
);
```

Or you can also just omit the HOC type, and TypeScript will infer the correct type from the function definition.

Comment: Yes, thank you a lot! This solves TS errors, however, if I import withFirebase(Component) from some other file it says I didn't provide firebase prop (which I did in HOC) and asks me to implicitly set it. How do I solve it, sir?

Comment: fixed return type to ```React.ComponentType<Omit<T, keyof WithFirebase>> & WithFirebase``` and it seems to be fine! Thanks!

Comment: Is there any way to do this from the component itself instead the HOC?