# How to set function props type for its child in Typescript? Property 'children' does not exist on type TS2339

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

For reference, I am using React `16.9.0` and Typescript `3.5.3`. If you install `Create React App` and create a Typescript project, you can add the following minimal example to reproduce the problem:

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

interface TreeComponentProps {
  recursion_level: number;
}

interface TreeComponentState {
}

class TreeComponent extends React.Component<TreeComponentProps, TreeComponentState>
{
  constructor(props: TreeComponentProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  render() {
    console.log( 'I was triggered during TreeComponent render...' );

    // const ListElements: any = (props: any) =>
    const ListElements: React.FunctionComponent<TreeComponentProps> = (props: TreeComponentProps) =>
    {
      if( props.recursion_level > 1 )
      {
        return (
          <ol>
            {props.children}
          </ol>
        );
      }
      else {
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            {props.children}
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      }
    }

    if( this.props.recursion_level > 3 ) {
      return <div> End recursion on {this.props.recursion_level}... </div>
    }

    return (
      <ListElements>
        <div> recursion_level {this.props.recursion_level + 1} <br /> </div>
        <TreeComponent key={0} recursion_level={ this.props.recursion_level + 1 }/>
      </ListElements>
    )
  }
}

interface AppProps {
}

interface AppState {
}

class App extends React.Component<AppProps, AppState>
{
  private recursion_level: number;

  constructor(props: AppProps) {
    super(props);

    this.recursion_level = 0;
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  render() {
    console.log( 'I was triggered during App render:', this.state )

    return (
        <TreeComponent key={0} recursion_level={ this.recursion_level }/>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

-->

```
Property 'children' does not exist on type 'TreeComponentProps'.  TS2339

    27 |         return (
    28 |           <ol>
  > 29 |             {props.children}
       |                    ^
    30 |           </ol>
    31 |         );
    32 |       }
```

If I replace the line:

```js
const ListElements: React.FunctionComponent<TreeComponentProps> = (props: TreeComponentProps) =>
// -->
const ListElements: any = (props: any) =>
```

Then, everything works fine and the page is generated correctly:

```
recursion_level 1
recursion_level 2
recursion_level 3
recursion_level 4
End recursion on 4...
```

I already researched and accordingly to this question [How to use children with React Stateless Functional Component in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40748397/how-to-use-children-with-react-stateless-functional-component-in-typescript/56026992) this is the correct syntax:

> Since React 16.8, the names `React.SFC` and `React.StatelessComponent` are depricated. Actually, they have become aliases for `React.FunctionComponent` type or `React.FC` for short.
>
> You would use them the same way though:
>
> ```
> const MyStatelessComponent : React.FunctionComponent<MyProps> = props =>
>     <div>
>         <p>{props.propInMyProps}</p>
>         <p>{props.children}</p>
>     </div>
> ```

How can I correctly set my internal function props type for typescript without having to keep using any everywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly declare the type of `MyStatelessComponent` as it can be inferred.

Also since you don't use `children` in your second `TreeComponent` declaration so you need to mark `children` optional to remove type errors.

You're also missing the prop `recursion_level={this.props.recursion_level}` to your `ListElements` component

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

interface TreeComponentProps {
  recursion_level: number;
  children?:React.ReactNode
}

interface TreeComponentState {
}

class TreeComponent extends React.Component<TreeComponentProps, TreeComponentState>
{
  constructor(props: TreeComponentProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  render() {
    console.log( 'I was triggered during TreeComponent render...' );

    // const ListElements: any = (props: any) =>
    const ListElements = (props: TreeComponentProps) =>
    {
      if( props.recursion_level > 1 )
      {
        return (
          <ol>
            {props.children}
          </ol>
        );
      }
      else {
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            {props.children}
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      }
    }

    if( this.props.recursion_level > 3 ) {
      return <div> End recursion on {this.props.recursion_level}... </div>
    }

    return (
      <ListElements recursion_level={this.props.recursion_level}>
        <div> recursion_level {this.props.recursion_level + 1} <br /> </div>
        <TreeComponent key={0} recursion_level={ this.props.recursion_level + 1 }/>
      </ListElements>
    )
  }
}

interface AppProps {
}

interface AppState {
}

class App extends React.Component<AppProps, AppState>
{
  private recursion_level: number;

  constructor(props: AppProps) {
    super(props);

    this.recursion_level = 0;
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  render() {
    console.log( 'I was triggered during App render:', this.state )

    return (
        <TreeComponent key={0} recursion_level={ this.recursion_level }/>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```